# Q: prove or disprove that $\{(x^2, x^3): x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I need to prove or disprove that the relation $R$ is a function.

$$R = \{(x^2, x^3): x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

If $R$ is a function - is it onto? Is it surjective?

I know that I need to check if $R$ is onto or to check if it's uniquely defined, but I'm not sure how to, exactly.

Comment: Before you can determine whether a function is onto you need to know the codomain.

Comment: also note that onto and surjective are the same thing. Maybe you mean surjective and/or injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is not a function because for $x = 1$ we have $(1,1) \in R$ and for $x= 
 -1$ we have $(1,-1)$ in $R$.

Therefore, $R$ would map $1$ to two different values.

Answer (score 3):

$$R=\{(x^2, x^3): x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$ is not a function.

Note that both $(4,8)$ and $(4,-8)$ are in the set $R$.

In fact for every $q\in \mathbb{Q} $ , $(q^2, q^3)$ and $(q^2, -q^3)$ are in $R$ which makes it far from being a function.

Comment: $R = \{(x^3, x^2): x \in \mathbb{R}\} is a function. The others are not.

Comment: Is it enough to say that for if $(a,b) ∈ R$, $a = x^2$ and $b = x^3$ and $(a,c) ∈ R$, $c=x^2$ than R is function because b = c?

it's just so trivial, i can't think of any proof that will have more details.

Comment: I did not understand your logic.

Comment: i'm referring to the proof that this relation is a function. and i'm asking about the details of the proof. because this Q. is simple, than there's not much to write, so when trying to prove that the case for $R = \{(x^3, x^2): x \in \mathbb{R}\} is in fact a function, all i need to do is repeat over the definition of a function, correct?

Answer (score 2):

It can't be a function because $(1,1) = (1^2,1^3)$ and $(1,-1) = ((-1)^2, (-1)^3)$ are both in $R$.

Answer (score 2):

$R$ is a function if for every $x^2$ there is a unique $(x^2,x^3)\in R$. However this doesnt hold, because for $x^2=1$ we have that $x=1$ or $x=-1$, and consequently $x^3=-1$ or $x^3=1$.

Comment: is it still not a function if $$R = \{(x^3, x^2): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ 
and R is a relation over $\mathbb{R}$ and not over $\mathbb{Q}$?
or if  $$R = \{(x^2, x^3): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ and R is over $\mathbb{R}$? 

or if  $$R = \{(x^2, x^3): x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
all of the above isn't functions, right?

i assume that because   $\mathbb{R}\subseteq$ $\mathbb{Q}$ than everything that imply on $\mathbb{Q}$  implies on $\mathbb{R}$, correct?

Comment: @Jenen not everything that works on $\Bbb Q$ works on $\Bbb R$. In this case yes, but in this case are essentially the same because the same reasons works for $x^2$ or $x^3$ if the belong to $\Bbb R$. For your first question: the set $\{(x^3,x^2):x\in\Bbb R\}$ is a function because the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is injective, and the map $x\mapsto x^2$ is a function.